# create pdf file using itext and upload it to server with other filed android

Tags: android, database, itext

I create pdf file using `itext`. This is the code:

```
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException ,IOException {
        // create folder to save the pdf

        // new FileOutputStream("/Internal storage/")

        File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "FolderName");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdir();
            Log.i("creat", "Pdf Directory created");
        }






        // end creat folder

        // create file name using todaydate.

        Date date = new Date() ;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder +"/"+ timeStamp + ".pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        //Step 1
        Document document = new Document();

        //Step 2
        PdfWriter   writer =  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

        //Step 3
        document.open();

        //Step 4 Add content

        document.add(new Paragraph("\n\nTAX INVOICE.\n"));


        document.add(new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n*THIS IS COMPUTER GENERATED INVOICE NO SIGNATURE REQUIRED."));



        //Step 5: Close the document
        document.close();




UploadToServer(myFile,userid,username);

    }
```

Now in the function `UploadToServer(myFile, userid, username);` as it showing am giving the myFile Type File and, `userid` and username Type String.

I want this function to upload the pdf file let say to this folder "www.ccc.com/pdffiles", and create a row in `pdffile` database content the URL to that pdf file, username, and `userid`

also from another activity i want to view pdf file from URL where I will get the url from pdffile database

Comment: What is the actual question? As far as iText is concerned, the PDF should be finalized at the end of `document.close()`.

Comment: yes now i want to upload this pdf file to my online database

Comment: and what is keeping you from doing so?

Comment: how to do that basically this is why i ask here , how to upload bro :D

Comment: That first of all depends on the upload mechanisms the server in question offers. Which does it offer?

Comment: i use godaddy Web Hosting , usually i enter data to my database from android app using php where the android app send data to the php file then the php file do the rest . if this is not what u mean  please let me know

Comment: *"where the android app send data to the php file"* - **how** does it do so? Does it use HTTP put? HTTP post? SFTP? SCP? UUCP? And please add additional information like that to the original question (there is an *edit* link underneath). That way other people are presented your question again.